# how to use content from subdomain to show on root via htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using wordpress on http://blog.example.com and I would to use the content from this subdomain to show on http://www.example.com

Can I do it via `.htaccess` file? If so, please advice me.

Comment: You need to check out mod_proxy and/or the use of the `[P]` flag in mod_rewrite

Comment: when you say content, what does that really mean, what type of content it is?